# Disappearing Footnote

Tags: formatting, footnotes, titles

**Goals:** I would like to have the title, author, date, and the table of content on the *same* page. I also want the capability of being able to have a footnote to the author.

**What I have done so far:** I came up with the following hack.  It works except for the footnote. (This is my first ever hack and therefore, it is probably pretty amateurish, may be something I should not be doing in the first place.)

I am open to any other method as long as I can achieve the stated goals with `hyperref` working.  (It would be also nice if I can have control over the fonts used.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks, hypertexnames]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[1]{%
\begin{center}%
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \let \footnote \thanks
    {\huge\bfseries \@title \par}%
    \vskip 2em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        {\bfseries \@author}
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date \par}%     
  \section*{\center{#1}}
  \end{center}\par
    \@starttoc{toc}%
      }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\title{This is a test}
\author{John Doe\footnote{where is the foot note?}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{Table of Contents}
\chapter{Preface}
 \lipsum[1]
\chapter{First Thing}
  \lipsum[2]
  \chapter{Second Thing}
  \lipsum[3]
   \chapter{Third Thing}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The first page of the output is given below.
[image]

Comment: +1 for defining  the goals, not only the problem with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need `report`?

If you could switch to `article` you could do it with 'standard'. But you must change chapter to section, section to subsection...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%some additional requested format changes
\usepackage{sectsty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\sectionfont{\huge\bfseries}

\title{This is a test}
\author{John Doe\footnote{where is the foot note?}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Preface}
 \lipsum[1]
\section{First Thing}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Second Thing}
  \lipsum[3]
  \section{Third Thing}
  \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I also want to use the hyperref package.  I mentioned this at the end of my question.  (Don't take the +1 off for not including this among the goals.:)  I will check and see if your code works with hyperref.  If so, then this is pretty clean.

Comment: @Sony There should be no problem with hyperref.

Comment: After changing `\title` command to `\title{\huge\bfseries This is a test}`, after centering the TOC Contents, after adding `\pagebreaks` between sections, and after adding `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}` I got the desired output _except_ for one thing.  I do not see how to left align titles of sections without a hack. (That does not mean it cannot be done without a hack, but I do not know how to do it.)  I _really_ wanted to accept this answer.:)

Comment: Instead `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}` you should `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`. But I think `scrartcl` may be another solution - give me some time, I will check.

Comment: I made a test with class `scrartcl`. It solve some things (e.g. the title), but the font change and there are some more chnages. I think, it would be to much to adapt.

Comment: Thanks.  `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` fixed the left alignment problem. If you use the `\secsty` package and add `\sectionfont{\huge\bfseries}`after the `tableofcontents` then we have a solution without a hack.  If you fix your answer accordingly, I will accept your answer.  (I do not think Werner would mind.)

Comment: I added sectsty  and the change of sectionfont.

Answer (score 7):

This is very common; that a `\foonote` is swallowed. A similar situation happens when [using `\footnote` within a `table`](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab). One way around this is to typeset a `\footnotemark` inside `\author`, and then typeset a `\footnotetext` outside. Here's a little *hack* to do this:

![enter image description here][1]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks, hypertexnames]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[1]{%
\begin{center}%
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \let \footnote \thanks
    {\huge\bfseries \@title \par}%
    \vskip 2em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        {\bfseries \@author}
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date \par}%     
  \section*{\center{#1}}
  \end{center}\par
    \@starttoc{toc}%
      }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\title{This is a test}
\author{John Doe\footnotemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{Table of Contents}
\makeatletter
{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{*}% Print * for counter value
\footnotetext{where is the foot note?}}
\makeatother
\chapter{Preface}
 \lipsum[1]
\chapter{First Thing}
  \lipsum[2]
  \chapter{Second Thing}
  \lipsum[3]
   \chapter{Third Thing}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{document}​
```

In order to maintain consistency in footnote referencing (and since I'm not sure how extensive you want to use the footnote symbol numbering), I've temporarily renewed how the `footnote` counter is displayed:

```
{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{*}% Print * for counter value
\footnotetext{where is the foot note?}}
```

The temporary change just affects the display of the counter within the group.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1cfL.png

Comment: Ok, your answer was 42 (!) seconds faster! (And it does not need `footmisc`). +1 for that.

Comment: @Stephen: Yours is perhaps more general. However, as mentioned in my answer, I'm not sure how extensive the OP's use of `\footnote` would be within `\author`. Mine would be just a quick-fix for this situation.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you very much.  It will take me some time to analyze all the wonderful solutions.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the link.  After reading it and reading Lamport's 6th chapter, I think I know what is happening.  Why do you need `/makeatletter` and `\makeatother` wrapping of the `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}`?

Comment: @Sony: For one, if you *don't* use `\makeatletter`, you will be greeted with a bunch of errors! The reason is that `@` is a reserved symbol and should be treated "with care", which `\makeatletter` does. `\makeatother` reverts this action to its regular form. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)

Comment: @werner: I compiled your code successfully _without_ the wrapping.  Are you talking about error messages in `log file`?

Comment: @Sony: You should have received some error messages in your `.log` file, yes. It could be that your compiler is set to ignore (or adapt to) those kind of messages through a command-line option. I'm not very familiar with that, since I try to avoid errors/warnings. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
```

(http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) for the symbol (before hyperref!) and then just use `\footnotemark` where you want the footnotemark and `\footnotetext{...}` after the TOC:

```
\author{John Doe\footnotemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{Table of Contents}
\footnotetext{Here is the foot note!}
```

Edit: without footmisc package and applying little change to your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks, hypertexnames]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[1]{%
\begin{center}%
%    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}% DELETED
    \let \footnote \thanks
    {\huge\bfseries \@title \par}%
    \vskip 2em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        {\bfseries \@author}
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date \par}%     
  \section*{\center{#1}}
  \end{center}\par
    \@starttoc{toc}%
      }
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\title{This is a test}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}% INSERTED    
\author{John Doe\footnotemark}% INSTEAD OF \footnotetext{...}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{Table of Contents}
\footnotetext{Here is the foot note!}% INSERTED
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}% INSERTED
% \chapter{...} resets the footnote number to one
\chapter{Preface}
 \lipsum[1]
 This is a test.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
\chapter{First Thing}
  \lipsum[2]
  \chapter{Second Thing}
  \lipsum[3]
   \chapter{Third Thing}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this affect *all* footnotes within the remainder of the document as well?

Comment: Yes, which is well when wished by the OP but bad otherwise.

Comment: @Stephen: Thank you.  I will have to wait till tomorrow to analyze your suggestion.  I do not mind experimenting.  So, you are good.

Comment: @Stephen: I read the `footmisc' manual and it says that "This option resets footnote numbering for each page of the document."  So, I checked by adding few statements with footnotes to subsequent chapters.  The results are not good for the project I am working in, as I need numbered footnotes in the chapters.  But it is always nice to learn something new.

Comment: OK, I added a solution without `footmisc`. That solution will use a star for the first footnote only and normal (Arabic numbers) afterwards. I tried to change only little of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be ok for you to change `\maketitle` and not `\tableofcontents`? Or better, define a new `\maketitleWithToc`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks, hypertexnames]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
  \newcommand\maketitleWithToc{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
%%%Insertion start
\section*{\center{Table of contents}}
\@starttoc{toc}
%%%Insertion end
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\title{This is a test}
\author{John Doe\footnote{where is the foot note?}}

\begin{document}
\maketitleWithToc

\chapter{Preface}
 \lipsum[1]
\chapter{First Thing}
  \lipsum[2]
  \chapter{Second Thing}
  \lipsum[3]
   \chapter{Third Thing}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: At this point, I am experimenting.  Therefore, I am open to any suggestion.

Comment: This works with minor modifications.  Now I have several avenues to take.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting this solution *only* to capture the full conversation below the accepted answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks, hypertexnames]{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\title{\huge\bfseries This is a test}
\author{\textbf{John Doe}\footnote{where is the foot note?}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\center\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\sectionfont{\huge\bfseries}
\begin{flushleft}
\section{Preface}
\vspace{10pt}
 \lipsum[1]
 \pagebreak
\section{First Thing}
\vspace{10pt}
  \lipsum[2]
  \pagebreak
  \section{Second Thing}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \lipsum[3]
  \pagebreak
  \section{Third Thing}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```