# Using AAS template, how to add footnote to title made with "\title" command?

Tags: footnotes, titles

I'm using the AAS template, linked [here](http://www.univelt.com/FAQ.html#SUBMISSION).  I'm new to LaTeX and trying to get a footnote to show up for my title, but commands such as `\footnote`, `\thanks`, and several others are not working.  The `\thanks` works for the authors, but not in `\title` or `\maketitle`.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, paper,11pt]{AAS}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=black, citecolor= black, urlcolor= black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{overcite}
\usepackage{footnpag} % make footnote symbols restart on each page
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\PaperNumber{#}

\begin{document}

\title{text...}

\author{name\thanks{info about author} \ and name\thanks{info about author}}

\maketitle{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So this seems specific to the template you may be using. Could you elaborate and provide the community with a minimal example that replicates your current behaviour? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: Related: [Disappearing Footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40071/5764) (you may try with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{..}`)

Comment: The template has you insert the title in \title{...} which is the first command after \begin{document}, and then there's an \author{...} line where you can input the authors' names and use \thanks{...} within it to create footnotes for author information to appear at the bottom of the page.  After the \author{...} command there is a \maketitle{} (empty inside bracket) command which is where the error occurs when trying to compile...this is when I've tried using \thanks{...} or \footnote or \footnotetext or \footnotemark within the \title command,...it doesn't compile, and has an error saying:

Comment: ! Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \def 
                
l.42 \maketitle
               {}
?

Comment: What is the `\documentclass` of this template? And what packages are loaded? Did you see the link I posted about [providing a minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)?

Comment: @Werner the \documentclass is paper and I've updated my question to hopefully be more of a minimum working example like you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to `\protect` your `\footnote` for it to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper]{AAS}% http://www.univelt.com/FAQ.html#SUBMISSION

\usepackage{hyperref}

\PaperNumber{1234}

\begin{document}

\title{A title\protect\footnote{\MakeLowercase{\MakeUppercase{A} title footnote.}}}

\author{First Author\thanks{Info about First Author.} \ and Second Author\thanks{Info about Second Author.}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Since the `\title` is set using `\MakeUppercase`, you'll have to work some magic for the content in the `\footnote` to set the way you want.

Comment: Given that the `AAS` document class kills the `\thanks` macro locally unless the `submit` option is set, I'd assume that they'll also frown on any work-arounds that use a `\footnote` directive instead of `\thanks`.

Comment: It's interesting they do that because the distro statements are definitely needed, since papers (not just journal submissions) are published...and many past papers (not just journal submissions) have the title footnote appearing.

Comment: @Werner this is perfect!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are exactly looking for but , have you tried following snippet?

```
\footnote{numbered footnote}

\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{footnote without number}
```

Comment: From what I understand: the OP wants something like `\title{Some title stuff\footnote{some footnote stuff}}`.

Comment: How does this answer address the OP's query?

Answer (score 0):

As asked before: which template or documentclass do you use.  In plain LaTeX classes (`article`, `report` and `book`) it should be no problem at all.  So my advise is: use standard classes, they should solve your problem.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Some title stuff\footnote{Some footnote content}}
\date{\today}\author{A. U. Thor}


\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: I will work on posing the question correctly, as I am new to LaTeX and stackexchange, but to answer your question I'm using a "paper" document class, if that makes sense?  I'm using a template made for a society/conference.

Answer (score 0):

The `AAS` document class lets you provide a footnote to the title only if the `submit` option is set at `\documentclass` time. (I take it that the `paper` option should be used for conference papers and that the `submit` option should be used for a submission to the JAS -- the society's  journal.)

If the `submit` option is not set, the following code from `AAS.cls` kicks in (cf. lines 180ff):

```
\if@submit%
  ...
\else% paper, or note
  ...
  \renewcommand\thanks[1]{}% locally kill the \thanks{} command
  ...
```

The upshot: If you really want to provide a footnote to go with the title, use the `submit` document class option. If you're not allowed to do so, *don't* provide a footnote to go with the title.